# Resize width and height of heatmap saved as html in iheatmapr

Tags: r, plotly, knitr, htmlwidgets

I would like to save in html a plot that I create using the `iheatmapr` R package and the `iheatmap` function. I use the `save_iheatmap` R function to save a *.html file with a dynamic plot which is produced by `save_iheatmap` (implement `plotly` R package). Here below I provide a reproducible example.
The problem that I encounter is that the size of the figure in the html file is not what I prefer. Thus, how I do specify the width and height of a html file to be saved in `save_iheatmap`? I tried to use `knitrOptions=list(vwidth = 500, vheight =1200)` as argument in `save_iheatmap` but it did not work.

```
#define Classes groups
    names_n = c('Apple','Banana','Orange','Kiwi','Ananas','Avocado','Lemon','Strawberry')

#define number of samples per Class
list_n = c(5,10,20,3,6,7,10,22)

#define Samples types and IDs  
annot_file <- data.frame(Sample=paste0('P',1:4),SampleType=c('Water','Water','No_Water','No_Water'))

#define function to perform random sampling of values
GetRanValues<-function(sample_n, mean_n){
      res = rnorm(n=sample_n,mean=mean_n,sd = 1)
      return(res)
}


#create datframe used for creating the heatmap plot
final_data = NULL

for(u in 1:length(list_n)){
  
  rep_n=list_n[u]
  
  tmp_data = data.frame(ID=paste0(names_n[u],1:rep_n),Class = rep(names_n[u],rep_n),
                        P1=GetRanValues(rep_n,mean_n=-12),P2=GetRanValues(rep_n,mean_n=-13),
                        P3=GetRanValues(rep_n,mean_n=-15),P4=GetRanValues(rep_n,mean_n=-14))
 
  final_data=rbind(final_data,tmp_data)
   
}


dataExpr = as.matrix(final_data[,-c(1,2)])
rownames(dataExpr) = 1:nrow(dataExpr)

#row annotation# 
row_annotation = as.data.frame(final_data$Class)
names(row_annotation) = 'Class'
#row annotation#

#col annotation##
rownames(annot_file) = annot_file$Sample
annot_file$Sample = NULL
col_annotation = annot_file
names(col_annotation) = " "
#col annotation#


heat_plot = iheatmapr::iheatmap(dataExpr, y=final_data$ID,
                                 row_title = "ID", col_title = "Sample",
                                 cluster_cols = 'none', cluster_rows = 'none',
                                 row_annotation = row_annotation, col_annotation = col_annotation,
                                 scale = "rows")

iheatmapr::save_iheatmap(p = heat_plot, filename = 'test_heatmap.html'))
```